# Php JSON encode array and unexpected token error in decoding

Tags: javascript, php, json

I got an array from an SQL query, encoded it and when I decode in javascript I receive the error

> Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0

The `var_dump` of the array before the encode:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["order_id"]=> string(10) "1512642144" 
["order_erp_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["order_type"]=> string(3) "web" 
["order_date"]=> string(23) "2017-12-07 11:22:24.263" ["order_total"]=> 
string(4) "0.00" ["order_desc1"]=> string(3) "web" ["order_desc2"]=> 
string(4) "test" ["no_items"]=> string(1) "0" ["order_count"]=> int(1) 
["item_arr"]=> string(0) "" } } 
[{"order_id":"1512642144","order_erp_id":"0","order_type":"web",
"order_date":"2017-12-07 11:22:24.263","order_total":"0.00",  
"order_desc1":"web","order_desc2":"test","no_items":"0",
"order_count":1,"item_arr":""}]
```

then I  encode and send it with:

```
echo json_encode($order_item_arr);
```

On the client side, I receive the data and before the decoding step I have this from the `console.log(data);` in javascript:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(10) {
["order_id"]=>
string(10) "1512642144"
["order_erp_id"]=>
string(1) "0"
["order_type"]=>
string(3) "web"
["order_date"]=>
string(23) "2017-12-07 11:22:24.263"
["order_total"]=>
string(4) "0.00"
["order_desc1"]=>
string(3) "web"
["order_desc2"]=>
string(4) "test"
["no_items"]=>
string(1) "0"
["order_count"]=>
int(1)
["item_arr"]=>
string(0) ""
  }
}


[{"order_id":"1512642144","order_erp_id":"0","order_type":"web",
"order_date":"2017-12-07 11:22:24.263","order_total":"0.00",  
"order_desc1":"web","order_desc2":"test","no_items":"0", 
"order_count":1,"item_arr":""}]
```

So it looks like quite ok, and when I decode it with `JSON.parse(data);` I have the error:

```
VM414:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't output `var_dump` on your PHP page, it invalidates the json on that page. Remove the `var_dump()` and the errors will go away.

As you can see from:

> Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0

That the error is occurring due to `array(1) {`, which is not a valid json. And is breaking the entire json data along with it.

So, just remove the `var_dump()`.

Look at this:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(10) {
["order_id"]=>
string(10) "1512642144"
["order_erp_id"]=>
string(1) "0"
["order_type"]=>
string(3) "web"
["order_date"]=>
string(23) "2017-12-07 11:22:24.263"
["order_total"]=>
string(4) "0.00"
["order_desc1"]=>
string(3) "web"
["order_desc2"]=>
string(4) "test"
["no_items"]=>
string(1) "0"
["order_count"]=>
int(1)
["item_arr"]=>
string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Removing `var_dump()` will remove the above part and, only thing which will remain is the string below, which is valid json.

```
[{"order_id":"1512642144","order_erp_id":"0","order_type":"web",
"order_date":"2017-12-07 11:22:24.263","order_total":"0.00",  
"order_desc1":"web","order_desc2":"test","no_items":"0", 
"order_count":1,"item_arr":""}]
```

Answer (score 3):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0

So the very first character in your "JSON" is `a`, which can't be valid JSON. And your `echo json_encode($order_item_arr);` line will not output it.

> The var_dump of the array before the encode:
>
> ```
> array(1) { [0]=> array
> ```

… and there is your problem. You can see that the first character is `a`.

You are trying to parse your var_dump as if it were JSON.

Don't do that. Parse the JSON instead.

Comment: Thanks, how can I correctly encode the array without sending the 'array(1) . . .'

Comment: @StefanoMaglione — Do. Not. Use. `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() is used to convert a string containing JSON notation into a Javascript object.

Your code turns the object into a string (by calling .toString()) in order to try to parse it as JSON text.
The default .toString() returns "[object Object]", which is not valid JSON; hence the error